# async does not have whole object in iteration

Tags: node.js, async.js

I use async.eachSeries to iterate over an array. The array looks like:

```
{ filename: '20171-132.pdf',
  content: [base64 encoded file]
}
```

With a loop I loop through the items to get the contents.

```
async.eachSeries(attach, function(item, callback){
    console.log("ITEM", item);
    var attachment = {
        filename: item.filename,
        content: item.content.split("base64")[1],
        encoding: 'base64'
    }

    attachments.push(attachment);
    callback();
}, function(){
    console.log("done");
})
```

But, in the log of 'item', I have only filename, with as result, that the code stops on item.content.split, because it's undefined.
Anybody any idea whats happening here and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working on an object, not an array.

```
{ 
   filename: '20171-132.pdf',
   content: [base64 encoded file]
}
```

Square brackets are the JSON representation of an array.
So if `item` would look like this instead;

```
[
    { 
       filename: '20171-132.pdf',
       content: [base64 encoded file]
    }
]
```

then I'm guessing it will fix your problem.